# Fantasy movie where a young guy finds the love of his life through a magical doorway

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am really sorry for the small amount of details, and I'm not even sure it is an English movie.

As far as I remember, a young guy who works in an old diner/restaurant (may be a pizza place) one day goes behind this restaurant/diner/or whatever place to bring something, and he accidentally discovers a magic door which takes him to another universe or a heavenly kind of place. In there is beach that I can remember, and the first time he goes into this place, the air is not even like air. For example he touches the air with his fingers and it is like water, or like the scene in *The Matrix* when Neo touches the mirror in the first movie, and the mirror acts like plasma, but only it happens in the air in the movie.

Then this young man meets a girl and they fall in love. Even though I am not sure, I think some bad stuff happens in this world too, and this young man turns back and consults his boss or maybe father, and decides to go back through the door to that world again to save the girl.

I have seen this movie when I was a little kid. Not even sure it is an English movie, because I watched the movie in another language and the name (again, not sure, just guessing and remembering that way) was "Chinese Restaurant's Door" or something like that.

I am really sorry for the small amount of details, but this is all I remember. like I said, I watched this a long time ago when I was a kid. It was probably a '90s, or at the very latest, early-2000s movie.

Edit: I can't remember the time, but it was a dubbed movie on TV, and I don't know what the original language was (could've been be English). I watched it between 1997 and 2000, but since it was on TV, it might have been produced years earlier. The ethnicity of the characters was white European, and it is a definitely a family movie. I don't remember anything more than this.

Comment: What language did you watch it in? Where were you when you watched it? What was the ethnicity of the protagonist and the love interest? When were you a little kid and watched this? Was there magic in this other world? Other ways it was different?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: I can't remember the time but I remember it was a dubbed movie on TV and I don't know what the original language was (could be English). I watched in between 1997 and 2000 but since it was on TV, it might have produced even years earlier. The ethnicity of the characters were white European looking and it is a definitely a family movie. I don't remember more than these.

Thanks for your help

Comment: @user156427 - What language was the movie dubbed into when you watched it?

Comment: It was dubbed in Turkish

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be [*Under the Chinese Restaurant* (1987)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0208464)?  It has several matching elements:

- The date is approximately right
- The title mentions a "Chinese Restaurant" (original title *Sotto il ristorante cinese*)
- The protaganest goes through a door to a surreal beach setting
- He meets a girl (and her father)

I didn't find a mention of the air, but perhaps thats what they mean by surreal.

The original Italian version can be seen on youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yefTwkC5lC0).

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess memory can be deceiving sometimes since I remember some pieces/elements differently in the movie and of course some effects as well. Nevertheless this is the movie and in fact even the name matches.